# Wall insulation

Tags: insulation

A few walls in my home are not insulated properly and I would like to add something before the cold weather here in NYC. The wall is more than 10 feet wide and more then likely wood studs every 16”. How can I add insulation to my walls without ripping them down and what kind of insulation would I use?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to get some blown in.  But you have to make coin size holes in your plaster wall and then patch them afterwards.

Another would be to put another layer of plaster board on with insulation in between.

Comment: Depending on the the type of construction, the holes for blowing in insulation can sometimes be made on the outside of the house.

Comment: Very true, @SteveSh, however, In many parts of NYC that's not particularly practical. Plus the added drawback of having all those holes in the _outside_ of your house, allowing weather in. (Speaking from experience - that was done to my house prior to my purchase, the little plastic caps don't seal all that well and they become brittle, break, and fall out over time, too.) I'd rather refinish the inside than the outside...